# What else could "have to" mean except "must"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It seems that in almost all cases "have to" means "be obliged to" and "must" and "have to" are interchangeable.However, I’ve noticed that in some cases it doesn’t seem to make sense if "have to" is replaced by "must".

1.Shaker is a courageous, resilient, kind and thoughtful person who has faced the worst the world ***has to*** offer and survived.

2.Let’s listen to what she ***has to*** say.(seeing she is an expert)

Comment: It could have the sense of _possess_.

Comment: @Lawrence  oh right!Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, it's (have) (to say/suggest/offer...) in the sense of possessing an idea or resource which you make available to others. This is not the same usage as (have to) meaning (be obliged to).